# Is it possible to return User ID to a field when referencing an email address in text field?

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, lead-assignment

I am trying to look at a field that gets populated by a vendor integration with our employee's email address, and assign lead ownership based on that.

I was intending to try to lookup the User ID and input into a separate field with a process and from there change the owner referencing that user ID, but am having difficulties.

I feel like it should be easy to accomplish this, am I overthinking it?

Comment: What condition are you using to select the appropriate User once you get the email address? Is it “find user with email address matching” principle or some other condition? You mentioned you are having difficulties, elaborate further and include what you have tried so far.

Comment: Can you include some more info on what you have already done? if you are using email address match as @TSmith asked, you might not even need another field, you could just do that on the fly if showing look up user field is not needed.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please take a minute to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) then [edit] your question to add detail. Note that the community expect questions to include specific technical detail (e.g. snippets of source code or details of flows etc.) to demonstrate what you've tried along with explanation of the specific issue. As it stands, if you don't edit the question, this is likely to get closed without answer.